# Ubuntu Mate 20.4 (Focal) doesn't not go to sleep mode

Tags: nvidia, suspend, ubuntu-mate

My working station (RTX 2080 + Ryzen 3700X) with mate ubuntu 20.04 refuses to sleep.
When I do Shutdown/sleep, it logs out of the session but does not actually go into sleep mode.
Here are some infos:

```
foo@foo-workstation:~$ nvidia-smi 
Tue Aug 16 17:59:52 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05    Driver Version: 495.29.05    CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   58C    P0    58W / 250W |    858MiB /  7959MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

and some more:

```
foo@foo-workstation:~$ systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
WHO   UID  USER  PID  COMM            WHAT                                                  WHY                                     MODE 
foo 1000 foo 5605 mate-power-mana handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-lid-switch Mate power manager handles these events block
```

What I already did:

- Purge all nvidia packages and install nvidia-driver-495.
- Read various threads on this topic none of which helps.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*This may work for you*.  I use it in a script to do some low-level disk drive unlock before doing changes to on-disk manufacturer security settings.

The relevant section in my script is this:

```
echo "\n Computer will go to into 'suspend' (or sleep state) in\n\n\t\t  >> 15 sec << \n\n AFTER suspension, simply hit the return key to wake it up again ..."
sleep 15

echo -n mem > /sys/power/state

hdparm -I ${BlockDev} >${TMP}.2 2>&1
```

The basis of the logic is derived from the description provided [**here**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt).  That gives options for you if you want to tweek the behaviour by varying the value sent to the "state" file.  For some distros, you may need to use **disk** instead of **mem**.

If interested, let me know and I can share the full script in this answer (long and complicated).